# check that string starts and ends with a specific pattern in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a table which is having string values

```
data_table = {'(?P<smartcache>.+)$', 'css', '123454', '(?P<version>.+)$'}
```

I am trying to see if a string `startswith` '(?P<' and `endswith` ')$' .
I want a string in output which will be like

```
output_table = '/smartcache/css/123454/version'
```

I am facing problem to fetch values which are passed with patterns
like I want to fetch `'smartcache'` from  `(?P<smartcache>.+)$`.

My Try:

```
out_string_value = (string.match(uri_regex, '[^(?P<].+[)$]')
```

here I am getting output as `smartcache>.+)$` but I want `smartcache`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local uri_regex = '(?P<smartcache>.+)$'
local out_string_value = uri_regex:match('^%(%?P<([^>]+)>.*%)%$$')
print(out_string_value)
```

The Lua pattern `^%(%?P<([^>]+)>.*%)%$$` is similar to the regex `^\(\?P<([^>]+)>.*\)\$$` except that Lua pattern uses `%` to escape magic characters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the intricacies of Lua Pattern syntax, but in regex terms, this would be the pattern:

```
^\(\?P<([^>]+)>.*\)\$$
```

On [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/28), you can see the match.

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\(` matches an opening bracket
- `\?` matches a question mark
- `P<` matches literal characters
- `([^>]+)` captures any chars that are not `>` to Group 1
- `>` matches literal char
- `.*` matches any chars
- `\)` matches a closing bracket
- `\$` matches a dollar
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Thanks but i want to fetch value which is passed inside <> in same operation.

Comment: Added a capture group. The value will be in Group 1 (`$1`)

Comment: See the [new demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/28): the value is highlighted. This is Group 1, not sure the Lua syntax to retrieve it, probably `$1`

Comment: Thanks i got the idea :)

Comment: That's good new Prashant, let me know if you're able to use that in your code. :)